# Why does Kivy ScreenManager not recognize my screen in Kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

This is my first time asking a question, and a beginner to Python and Kivy.

While running a program using Kivy, I developed some screens which operated as planned. However, when adding a new screen, it was not recognized and this error was returned.

---

File "kivy_event.pyx", line 1154, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 1045, in on_current
screen = self.get_screen(value)

File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\screenmanager.py", line 1071, in get_screen
raise ScreenManagerException('No Screen with name "%s".' % name)

kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name "sign_up_screen_success".

---

Here is my main.py code:

```
import os
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\MyName\Documents\mobile app")

from kivy.app import App
import json
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from datetime import datetime

Builder.load_file('design.kv')

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    def sign_up(self):
        self.manager.current = "sign_up_screen"

class RootWidget(ScreenManager):
    pass

class SignUpScreen(Screen):
    def add_user(self, uname, pword):
        with open("users.json") as file:
            users = json.load(file)

        users[uname] = {'username': uname, 'password': pword,
            'created': datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")}

        with open("users.json", 'w') as file:
            json.dump(users, file)
        self.manager.current = "sign_up_screen_success"


class SignUpScreenSuccess(Screen):
    pass


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

And here is my .kv code:

```
<LoginScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            Label:
                text: "User Login"
            TextInput:
                hint_text: "Username"
            TextInput:
                hint_text: "Password"
            Button:
                text: "Login"
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Button:
                text: "Forgot Password?"
            Button:
                text: "Sign Up"
                on_press: root.sign_up()

<SignUpScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
            text: "Sign up for a space journey!"
        TextInput:
            id: username
            hint_text: "Username"
        TextInput:
            id: password
            hint_text: "Password"
        Button:
            text: "Submit"
            on_press: root.add_user(root.ids.username.text, root.ids.password.text)

<SignUpScreenSuccess>:
  GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    Label:
      text: "Sign up successful!"
    Button:
      text: "Login page"


<RootWidget>:
    LoginScreen:
        name: "login_screen"
    SignUpScreen:
        name: "sign_up_screen"
    SignUpScreenSuccess:
      name: "sign_up_screen_success"
```

From what I gathered, since I defined "sign_up_screen_success" to correspond with SignUpScreenSuccess in the RootWidget of my .kv code, I should proceed to a different screen. So, why is this not working?

SignUpScreen and LoginScreen worked fine, but I could not see any difference in code between those and SignUpScreenSuccess.

If I need to clarify anything else, let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure that it solves the problem, but in examples I've seen and according to the documentation:
https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html

The root widget in the kv doesn't have the <> brackets.

like so:

```
RootWidget:
    LoginScreen:
        name: "login_screen"
    SignUpScreen:
        name: "sign_up_screen"
    SignUpScreenSuccess:
      name: "sign_up_screen_success"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I've been working on Kivy aswell the last weeks. Could you try initialising the names like this:

```
<LoginScreen>:
    name: "login_screen"
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            Label:
                text: "User Login"
            TextInput:
                hint_text: "Username"
            TextInput:
                hint_text: "Password"
            Button:
                text: "Login"
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Button:
                text: "Forgot Password?"
            Button:
                text: "Sign Up"
                on_press: root.sign_up()

<SignUpScreen>:
    name: "sign_up_screen"
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        Label:
            text: "Sign up for a space journey!"
        TextInput:
            id: username
            hint_text: "Username"
        TextInput:
            id: password
            hint_text: "Password"
        Button:
            text: "Submit"
            on_press: root.add_user(root.ids.username.text, root.ids.password.text)

<SignUpScreenSuccess>:
  name: "sign_up_screen_success"
  GridLayout:
    cols: 1
    Label:
      text: "Sign up successful!"
    Button:
      text: "Login page"


<RootWidget>:
    LoginScreen:        
    SignUpScreen:        
    SignUpScreenSuccess:
```

I coded my screens like this, this should work I think

Comment: I tried to code it like that, but now for some reason a new error is popping up.

It says that line 40 has an invalid indentation, and has to be a multiple of 4 spaces. I really have no clue why that's showing up, since I've triple checked that it is 4 spaces.

However, this error showed up in my initial .kv program as well, so I guess it's not the code's fault, but something to do with my editor (Atom) or anything related.

Comment: I just saw that the <SignUpScreen> had different indentation than <SignUpScreenSucces>.
I use PyCharm btw